# Show/hide lists if value true - clear code (VBA, EXCEL)

Tags: vba, excel

please is it possible to write this code in clearest version? I have Sheets from 1-20 and values from 1-20 and need this check on every sheet if I opening workbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()       
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST").Cells(2, 2).Value = True Then

        Sheets("TP_OP_010").Visible = True
         Else
        Sheets("TP_OP_010").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If


        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST").Cells(3, 2).Value = True Then

       Sheets("TP_OP_020").Visible = True
         Else
        Sheets("TP_OP_020").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST").Cells(4, 2).Value = True Then

       Sheets("TP_OP_030").Visible = True
         Else
        Sheets("TP_OP_030").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Worksheet Naming conventions are consistent:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SheetName As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST")
        For i = 2 To 31
            SheetName = "TP_OP_" & Format((i - 1) * 10,"000")
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Visible = IIf(.Cells(i, 2).Value, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetVeryHidden)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Or use an Array of Worksheet Names:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SheetName As Variant
    i = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST")
        For Each SheetName In Array("TP_OP_010",  "TP_OP_020",  "TP_OP_030",  "TP_OP_040",  "TP_OP_050",  "TP_OP_060",  "TP_OP_070",  "TP_OP_080",  "TP_OP_090",  "TP_OP_100",  "TP_OP_110",  "TP_OP_120",  "TP_OP_130",  "TP_OP_140",  "TP_OP_150",  "TP_OP_160",  "TP_OP_170",  "TP_OP_180",  "TP_OP_190",  "TP_OP_200")
            i = i + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Visible = IIf(.Cells(i, 2).Value, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetVeryHidden)
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting error subscript out of range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Visible = IIf(.Cells(i, 2).Value, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetVeryHidden)

My values starting B2 to B20

Comment: @Nataniell you'll need to adjust the Worksheet Names.  Which version are you using?

Comment: It´s working now. I forget add TP_OP_200. Sorry and thanks for help :)

Comment: @Nataniell I'm happy that I was able to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (not sure about your worksheet naming though, so you may need to make an adjustment to that part of the code)

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim x As Long, c As Range

    Set c = Me.Sheets("OPERACE_EXIST").Columns(2)

    For x = 1 To 20

        Me.Sheets("TP_OP_" & Format(x, "000")).Visible = _
            IIf(c.Cells(x + 1).Value, True, xlSheetVeryHidden)

    Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: The sheet names are incrementing by 10.  Interesting using `Me` in the Worksheet Module to refer to the workbook.